# Error happens not always but just sometimes in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to execute a parallel program using MPI and C, I imposed the initial condition such that every run is always equal to the previous, but sometimes I get an error, the error is alternating this:

```
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] *** Process received signal ***
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] Signal code:  (0)
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007ff80f917c1d _sigtramp + 29
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000201 0x0 + 513
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007ff80f836ca5 abort + 123
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 3] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f74ca37 malloc_vreport + 888
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 4] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f761959 malloc_zone_error + 178
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 5] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f75a12b nanov2_guard_corruption_detected + 34
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 6] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f7596e9 nanov2_allocate_outlined + 374
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 7] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f73f59d nanov2_malloc + 526
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 8] 0   libopen-pal.40.dylib                0x000000010562f5eb opal_show_help_yyensure_buffer_stack + 128
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [ 9] 0   libopen-pal.40.dylib                0x000000010562f8b3 opal_show_help_yy_switch_to_buffer + 14
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [10] 0   libopen-pal.40.dylib                0x000000010562fdc5 opal_show_help_init_buffer + 22
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [11] 0   libopen-pal.40.dylib                0x000000010562e777 opal_show_help_vstring + 386
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [12] 0   libopen-rte.40.dylib                0x00000001057cb9e8 orte_show_help + 171
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [13] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010569c9ba backend_fatal + 606
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [14] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010569c73e ompi_mpi_errors_are_fatal_comm_handler + 159
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [15] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010569c3df ompi_errhandler_invoke + 99
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [16] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x00000001056d5b33 MPI_Recv + 651
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [17] 0   main                                0x00000001054dd1d6 main + 3958
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] [18] 0   dyld                                0x00007ff80f5bc310 start + 2432
[MBP-di-Simone:76276] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
 a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node MBP-di-Simone exited on signal 6 (Abort trap: 6).
```

Even if the executions are equal among them, it doesn't happen in every run. I can't understand what it means. Somebody can explain me the meaning of this error and how is possible that sometimes it happens and sometimes not?

Edit: here the link to the code: https://github.com/simonerusso97/bfr-clustering-parallelized
Note that it is a kind of cluster algorithm, the code is provided with the dataset in csv on which I'm doing my test

Edit: I searched for missing malloc cast and added it everywhere and the error changed showing this:

```
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] *** Process received signal ***
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] Signal code:  (0)
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007ff80f917c1d _sigtramp + 29
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x00007ff7b74bced0 0x0 + 140701908848336
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007ff80f836ca5 abort + 123
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 3] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f74ca37 malloc_vreport + 888
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 4] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f761959 malloc_zone_error + 178
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 5] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f745aa6 small_free_list_remove_ptr_no_clear + 1000
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 6] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007ff80f742f7c free_small + 619
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 7] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x0000000108c89115 mca_coll_base_comm_unselect + 11654
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 8] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x0000000108bf81aa ompi_comm_destruct + 32
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [ 9] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x0000000108bf9120 ompi_comm_finalize + 232
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [10] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x0000000108c13620 ompi_mpi_finalize + 923
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [11] 0   main                                0x0000000108a4671b main + 5163
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] [12] 0   dyld                                0x00007ff80f5bc310 start + 2432
[MBP-di-Simone:85691] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
 a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A system call failed during shared memory initialization that should
 not have.  It is likely that your MPI job will now either abort or
 experience performance degradation.

  Local host:  MBP-di-Simone.homenet.telecomitalia.it
  System call: unlink(2)         /var/folders/d6/st4lmq9x55bd2cw12j85xz8m0000gn/T//ompi.MBP-di-Simone.501/pid.85690/1/vader_segment.MBP-di-Simone.501.ae5e0001.1
  Error:       No such file or directory (errno 2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MBP-di-Simone.homenet.telecomitalia.it:85690] PMIX ERROR: UNREACHABLE in file server/pmix_server.c at line 2198
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node MBP-di-Simone exited on signal 6 (Abort trap: 6).
```

with this:

```
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] *** Process received signal ***
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] Signal code:  (0)
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] Failing at address: 0x0
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007ff80f917c1d _sigtramp + 29
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 2] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010f02d1aa ompi_comm_destruct + 32
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 3] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010f02e069 ompi_comm_finalize + 49
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 4] 0   libmpi.40.dylib                     0x000000010f048620 ompi_mpi_finalize + 923
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 5] 0   main                                0x000000010ee7b71b main + 5163
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] [ 6] 0   dyld                                0x00007ff80f5bc310 start + 2432
[MBP-di-Simone:86533] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
 a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A system call failed during shared memory initialization that should
 not have.  It is likely that your MPI job will now either abort or
 experience performance degradation.

  Local host:  MBP-di-Simone.homenet.telecomitalia.it
  System call: unlink(2) /var/folders/d6/st4lmq9x55bd2cw12j85xz8m0000gn/T//ompi.MBP-di-Simone.501/pid.86532/1/vader_segment.MBP-di-Simone.501.b2e00001.1
  Error:       No such file or directory (errno 2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MBP-di-Simone.homenet.telecomitalia.it:86532] PMIX ERROR: UNREACHABLE in file server/pmix_server.c at line 2198
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node MBP-di-Simone exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The strange thing is that the initial conditions are chosen in a way that the execution is always the same but the error isn't thrown in each run but only sometimes. Reading the error message it seems to happen in finalize() call but I can't understand why

Moreover very few times it give this message:

```
[MBP-di-Simone:86488] *** Process received signal ***
```

but it doesn't terminate, it just stay hang and I think that doesn't continue computation

Comment: I would suspect a race condition but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing a [mre].

Comment: I can leave the github link, it is difficult to give a minimal reproducible example, because I don't know what causes the error, anyway, with race condition do you mean that the root process is expecting a message from a certain process and instead receive a message form one other?

Comment: It may be difficult but give it a try or you'll very unlikely get any help. Remove piece by piece until it doesn't show the problem anymore. Replacing all the file read stuff should be the easiest part. Just make a static table of the values in the program.

Comment: You might try adding logging.  One trick is to append logs to a set of file like log-(thread-id).txt  or log-(process-id).txt for multiprocess so the threads / processes do not interfere with each other.    Another is to only log the unexpected values that will trigger the signal.  asserts and breakpoints or watch rules  might work with a debugger.

Comment: If it might be bad data. unexpected values, or a damaged CSV file you might write a separate applet that just reads the CSV and logs anything that is not what your app is designed for.

Comment: @DaveS I don't believe that data are corrupted, I run many times the program always on the same dataset and sometimes it gives this error and sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows that `MPI_Recv()` failed for an unknown reason, invoked the error handler (which is the default behavior) and the error handler crashed in `malloc()`. The name of the functions invoked by `malloc()` strongly suggests some kind of memory corruption rather than the system running out of memory.

Note the default behavior of Open MPI is to check MPI subroutines parameters (e.g. valid communicator, commited datatype, non negative count, ...) so the `MPI_Recv()` failure could be caused by invalid parameters or some internal failure. I would guess the latter but who knows.

My best bet would be to use `valgrind` and try to spot some memory corruption.
You might also try to force communications over TCP/IP in order to rule out some interconnect specific stuff that could confuse `valgrind`:

```
mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self ... valgrind ...
```

Comment: Do you think it could be a problem with my machine?

Comment: If you have overclocked the CPU, GPU, or RAM then definitely could be a too-aggressive overclock triggering corruption.  Many years ago intel released a factory-overclocked pentium to catch up with AMD, and it only failed for TomsHardware when compiling the linux kernel.  Basic stability tests for overclocking are not safe for all uses.

Comment: everything is possible. if you run on a cluster, make sure you run in exclusive mode (e.g. only one job per node), and if you run on a workstation, check the amount of available memory before running your job.